# Grape vine in shade predicament, will it fruit?

Tags: fruits, vines, sunlight, grape-vine, shade

I have purchased a 3 year old grape vine. It is about 6 to 7 feet long. Ready to be planted.

However, the growing place I have is in the corner of walls. The walls are about 7 ft long. If I grow this grape vine there, it will not get any direct sunlight in the bottom 7 ft. But it will have plenty of direct sunlight above 7 ft.

According to this video, grape vine can grow in shade, but will not fruit https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c0GeNhVeOvg

What will happen in my case where bottom 7ft of vine will not get direct sunlight, the rest will he plenty. will it fruit?

Comment: I am sure you will get fruit once the vine can get to the sun.  What I can't answer if only the parts of the vine in the sun will get Fruit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds roughly similar to a tradtional grape arbor situation, where the vines grow up to a latticed support where they spread out, get sun, and create shade below. The parts in the sun (with appropriate pruning) bear fruit.

[image: Grape arbor from undeneath]

*[Image source](https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fst.houzz.com%2Fsimgs%2F14316d7f0d69c5f6_4-0739%2Ftraditional-landscape.jpg&f=1&nofb=1&ipt=fd6cd2de756ab5c129a5b968b169d9c767208c96c825f89bdee147b05f3a4204&ipo=images) no endorsement implied*

Answer (score 3):

My vine grows up my porch, facing north west (and I'm located about 50°N).  It does get a little  summer sun but it's a shady spot.  It fruits pretty prolifically -- last year we got over 4 kg in the biggest picking.  But it does require good weather in late summer for the grapes to ripen well.

The fruit mostly appears on the higher, sunnier parts of the vine, but that's also to do with how far I cut it back.  I do get some lower down, where it's more shaded.

This is an unknown purple wine variety, so for eating they're quite pippy, but make excellent jelly and juice.